# How to pull revenue with nested event_params source and medium (GA4 BigQuery Extract)

Tags: google-bigquery

How do I properly pull revenue by nested event_params source and medium? (GA4 BigQuery Extract)

Sample query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = 'campaign') AS manual_campaign_name,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = 'source') AS manual_source,
  (SELECT value.string_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = 'medium') AS manual_medium,
  (SELECT value.double_value FROM unnest(event_params) WHERE key = 'value') AS revenue,
FROM 
  `table`
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example